# Splitting a geo polygon into multiple polygons of specific area

Tags: r, geospatial, polygon

I am trying to split a polygon on R into multiple polygons of equal areas.

I have the boundaries of the polygon which I need to split in boxes measuring 1km by 1km using R. I was wondering if this is possible using R.

For example:

```
x <- extent(c(40.97453103, 41.06321504, -92.47427103, -92.36617044))
plot(x)
```

This creates a box with the given bounds.
I am trying to create multiple boxes within the bounds of size 1km by 1km and then merge it on google maps using ggmap.

Comment: Interesting problem. One issue you will run into is your extent box is not exactly a unit of 1km (the coordinates I tested in the extent were 9.075km away from each other). So where is the reference point to start the 1km boxes? I.e. you'll have 9 full 1km squares, but then a small overflow box of just a .075km extent (for the side I tested).

Comment: That is a very good observation. the reference would be at the edge of the box. I will just have to neglect the 0.075 km in this case.

Comment: The answer below is in the right direction. Why not trim the extent then to exactly the 9km x 9km then use the answer below. You could determine the trim coordinates with geosphere package destPoint.

Comment: My other thought would be to rasterize (raster() ) and use a resolution setting with res() after trimming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `st_make_grid` function from the `sf` package but we don't know your coordinates reference system and the units used. 
Here is an example with grids of an arbitrary size :

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.5.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.2
x <- cbind(c(40.97453103, 41.06321504, 41.06321504, 40.97453103, 40.97453103),
           c(-92.47427103, -92.47427103, -92.36617044, -92.36617044, -92.47427103))

x <- st_sf(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(x))))
grid <- st_make_grid(x, cellsize = c(0.01,0.01))

par(mar = c(1,1,1,1))
plot(x)
plot(grid, add = T)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-02-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking. It's a good thought, but beware on this because as you say **These boxes are arbitrary size, not 1kmx1km**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I think i can use this to make my little project work!!